# Matlab - Return rows matrix which values are not included in the interval min and max

Tags: matlab

How do I list the products names  whose value is not included in the interval min and max?

```
mat ={
'Name','Value','Min','Max';
'A1','26','1','25';
'A2','25','12','34';
'A3','25','','';
'A4','25','13','45';
'A5','25','','';
'A6','4','1','2'}
```

In this case I would return the following values:

```
A1, (value 26 is not between 1 and 25)
A6,(value 4 is not between 1 and 2)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your given matrix, this will do the trick:

```
%// Extract and convert the values of interest
values = str2double(mat(2:end,2));

%// Extract & convert the bounds. 
%// Replace empties with appropriate values
mins = str2double(mat(2:end,3));    mins(isnan(mins)) = -inf;
maxs = str2double(mat(2:end,4));    maxs(isnan(maxs)) = +inf;

%// Extract the desired information. 
%// (Note that I ignore the headerline explicitly)
mat( [false; values < mins | values > maxs], 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example `mat` is invalid so I've interpreted it like this:

```
mat ={'A1', 26, 1   , 25;
      'A2', 25, 12  , 34;
      'A3', 25, -inf, inf;
      'A4', 25, 13  , 45;
      'A5', 25, -inf, inf;
      'A6', 4 , 1   , 2};
```

I've used `-inf` for unknown mins and `inf` for unknown maxs. Then you can get your result as follows.

```
mat(~(([mat{:,2}] > [mat{:,3}]) & ([mat{:,2}] < [mat{:,4}])),1)
```

If this is no good, then please post a proper complete example `mat` that we can reproduce.

---

For your new definition of `mat` you can do this:

```
mat ={
'A1','26','1','25';
'A2','25','12','34';
'A3','25','','';
'A4','25','13','45';
'A5','25','','';
'A6','4','1','2'};
```

note that I have removed your header line from `mat` because that will break things

```
for row = 1:size(mat,1)
     if strcmp(mat{row, 3},'')
         mat{row,3} = '-inf';
     end
     if strcmp(mat{row,4},'')
         mat{row,4} = 'inf';
     end 
 end

 num = cellfun(@str2num,mat(:,2));
 mini = cellfun(@str2num,mat(:,3));
 maxi = cellfun(@str2num,mat(:,4));

 mat(((num < mini) | (num > maxi)), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, cell values ​​are characters, I've edited the post by correct values, sorry for the invalid data.

Comment: I've add "num=...'UniformOutput', false);" to correct first error. But Last line generate this error: Undefined function or method 'lt' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: @TimeIsNear What first error??? As for the second... did you miss type `if` maybe?

Comment: first error is (I think first data row caused this):"Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false." I fixed this by start from second row

Comment: the result is 'A5' but I expected 'A1' and 'A6'

Comment: @TimeIsNear I did say in my answer that you need to remove that first line. But if you copy and paste my solution, you will get `'A1'` and `'A6'` back.